# OAuth 2.0 - Accessing Google Analytics Data and maintaining a session on redirect back to my site?

Tags: php, session, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I have a simple website to automate some maintenance tasks.  One of these is checking a wide amount of google analytics data in one view.

Currently I have no problems using the PHP Library provided by google to get the data and put it to good use.

However, my problem is that my website has a simple login thats based on sessions, and on redirect back to my web application the session is destroyed, causing my login "check" to kick me back to my maintenance login.  What is the preferred way to maintain my first login upon "authorization" from google?

Comment: So apparently this is not an oAuth problem but a session problem. - I can get this to work if I move session_start(); out of an include file (check.php) and put it as the first line of the file that the callback is referencing..  The check / session happens before anything else happens, why would the simple position of session_start() matter?  There is to my knowledge no other output nor any errors or warnings output regardless of the location, the difference is an empty session variable.